# Laravel Excel Import Write into Batches of Excel file

Tags: excel, laravel, import, maatwebsite-excel

I have a large number of records in an excel sheet which is taking too much time while importing to the 3 tables in database. To overcome this issue, I am trying to import it through batch by creating small excel files with less data so that I run queue jobs of laravel on it. I am trying with the below code but it doesn't work, it throws an error of Array to String conversion and also sub excel files are not creating. I am using excel Maatweb, but I am handling it through controller.

Can someone lead me please.

```
function importBatchFiles(Request $request)
{
 $this->validate($request, [
  'file'  => 'required|mimes:xls,xlsx,csv'
 ]);
 $file = $request->file('file');
 //$fileName='orders_'.$request->get('company_id').'_'.date('Y-m-d').uniqid().'.xlsx';
 if ($file->isValid()) {
      //$file->move('order_list', $fileName);
      $data = Excel::toArray(new OrdersImport, request()->file('file'));
      foreach($data as $key => $value)
      {
        foreach($value as $row)
        {
          $inputs[] = $row;
        }
      }
      $data1 = array_slice($inputs, 1);
      $parts = (array_chunk($data1, 500));

      foreach($parts  as $index => $part){
        $filename = resource_path('pending-files/'.date('Y-m-d').$index.'.'.$request->file->extension());
        file_put_contents($filename, $part);
      }

      return Response::json(['success' => 'Orders Queued for importing.']);
  }else{
    return Response::json(['error' => 'Some errror']);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the **WithChunkReading** concern, you can execute each chunk into a queue job. You can do so by simply adding the **ShouldQueue** contract.

For more details please refer to this link: https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/queued.html

Comment: Actually the data I am importing is for three tables and has a logic of checking existing records in all three tables, is it possible to implement the same logic in import class, the way I am doing it in a controller i.e. first I have to check if the customer exists, then check for existing order_id, etc.

Comment: @Muzafar Yes, you can do row validation inside the Import class. please go through this [link](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/validation.html)